# How can I use implode on bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have a create account method and within that an associative array called `userInfo`. This is the array:

```
$userInfo = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'salt'     => $this->passwordHash('Extra Protection is a good thing'),
        'password' => $this->passwordHash($password)
    );
```

Now I am "Trying" to use implode with the prepared statement. I seem to be getting a `No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement` error when it attempts to bind the parameters.

Here is the statement:

```
if ( ! ($stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $this->_info['Prefix'] . "users
    (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($userInfo))."`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")))
    {
        echo 'Prepare Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->bind_param('sss', implode("', '", $userInfo)))
    {
        echo 'Bind Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->execute())
    {
        echo 'Execute Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
    }
```

I originally used `real_escape_string` and the query did execute correctly. It's just the prepared statement that it doesn't like.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: `implode("', '", $userInfo)` gives **one** string while `bind_param('sss'` expects **three** strings

Comment: @u_mulder I tried doing just `s` but same problem...

Comment: one `s` means that you should have only one `?` in query text, not `3`.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks, that gets rid of the first error however now there is an error preparing, I'm guessing because there are three columns it's trying to insert into with only 1 value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't properly understand prepared statements. Each inserted value would be prepared according to it's table field definintion.
This is your query for example:

```
INSERT 
    INTO users (`username`, `salt`, `password`) 
    VALUES ('john', 'somesalt', 'somepassword');
```

So value `jonh` will be prepared according to `username` field settings, `somesalt` - according to `salt`, etc.

So what are your errors here (i skip `implode` and etc):

When you do:

```
$stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("INSERT INTO " 
    . $this->_info['Prefix']
    . "users  (`user`, `salt`, `password`) values (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', implode("', '", $userInfo))
```

it's wrong because query expects 3 string (`s`), each string will be prepared according to field settings, and you're giving only one.

When you change to this:

```
 $stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("INSERT INTO " 
    . $this->_info['Prefix']
    . "users  (`user`, `salt`, `password`) values (?)");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', implode("', '", $userInfo))
```

it's wrong too, because here comes query error. You want to insert three fields but give value for one field only.

So what you really should do is:

```
$stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("INSERT INTO " 
    . $this->_info['Prefix']
    . "users  (`user`, `salt`, `password`) values (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $userInfo['username'], $userInfo['salt'], $userInfo['password']);
```

So, in the end it's impossible to use `implode` with `bind_param` in mysqli (I hope it's mysqli), and if you want to know hot to use `bind_param` with array of values - you should read this comment on php.net - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073

Comment: Thank you, it didn't even cross my mind to reference each element like `$userInfo['key']`. It works now :)

Comment: Most people here don't understand russian, so you'd better link to English version of the manual